# How to chain these methods?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've created a service method where i can check if a given company ID already exists inside my database... this method is simple returning true or false:

```
    public checkIfOndernemingsnummerAlreadyExists(ondernemingsnummer: string): Observable<boolean> {
        const url = `${environment.apiUrl}/ondernemingen/exists/${ondernemingsnummer}`;
        return this.http.get<boolean>(url);
    }
```

Now i've created a sort of wizard where a user can create a new company in a certain steps.

In the first step, the user has to enter the company's ID number.
When going to the next step, i would like to check wether this given ID number already exists inside my database.

If it does not exist, the user can proceed to the next step inside the wizard.
If it does exist, a warning message should be show and the user should just stay at the current wizard step.

So i added the following code when submitting the company ID's inside the first step:

```
public submitOnderneming(): void {
    this.loading = false;
    this.isDuplicate = false;

    of(true).pipe(
      tap(() => this.loading = true),
      switchMap(() => this.kandidatuurService.checkIfOndernemingsnummerAlreadyExists(this.onderneming.ondernemingsnummer)),
      tap((res) => { this.isDuplicate = res; }),
      switchMap(() => { if (this.isDuplicate !== true) { return this.requestService.selectOnderneming(this.onderneming); }})
    ).subscribe(v => { this.loading = false; this.ref.detectChanges(); });
  }
```

But this is giving me the following error:

> You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

Now i guess that's because inside the 2nd switchMap i only return a value when the isDuplicate is not true. In the other case i don't return anything.

My requestService.selectOnderneming looks like this:

```
    public selectOnderneming(onderneming: OndernemingDetail): Observable<RequestSteps> {
        this.store.dispatch(new SetOndernemingOfRequest(onderneming));
        return this.gotoNextStep();
    }
```

So what should write inside the switchMap when the isDuplicate is true?
Or should i rearrange my code entirely?

What i want to achieve is:

1. set the loading property to true
2. call kandidatuurService.checkIfOndernemingsnummerAlreadyExists
3. based on this result set the isDuplicate property
4. when it's not a duplicate call requestService.selectOnderneming
5. when all finished set the loading property to false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is a better solution, but for a hopefully working version:

```
this.loading = true;
this.kandidatuurService.checkIfOndernemingsnummerAlreadyExists(this.onderneming.ondernemingsnummer)
 .pipe(tap((isDuplicate) => this.isDuplicate = isDuplicate),
       switchMap((isDuplicate) => (isDuplicate ? of(true) : this.requestService.selectOnderneming(this.onderneming))))
 .subscribe(v => { this.loading = false; this.ref.detectChanges(); });
```

Comment: This is giving me error:  InvalidPipeArgument: 'true' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Comment: You are right, your code is working correcty. The error at my side is generated by the line this.ref.detectChanges();

Comment: Inside my UI i have this div:  <div class="spinner" *ngIf="loading">
But my UI is not being updated, thats why i was using the detectChanges() method. But now this detectChanges is causing trouble and the UI is still not updated

Comment: Ok, i got it. Just had to change (isDuplicate ? of(true) : this.requestService.selectOnderneming(this.onderneming) to (isDuplicate ? of(RequestSteps) : this.requestService.selectOnderneming(this.onderneming) now all working fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try to diff your version with the following https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pipe-and-ui

Comment: You´re welcome. To help other readers please mark the most helping post.

Answer (score 0):

No need for two switchMaps, the reactive history begins with the first request, you can make it the beginning of your chain. Filter out responses that are duplicates, then switchMap, and that should be it.

Edit: as written below, `filter` should take care of `loading` flag, when returning false, because nobody else will have the opportunity.

```
this.loading = true;

this.kandidatuurService.checkIfOndernemingsnummerAlreadyExists(this.onderneming.ondernemingsnummer)
    .pipe(
        filter(
            //... logic checking for duplicates here
        ),
        switchMap(() => this.requestService.selectOnderneming(this.onderneming))
    )
    .subscribe( // subscribers here
```

Comment: I would guess he had to execute the subscribe part also in the duplicate case, implied `checkIfOndernemingsnummerAlreadyExists` will always give just one value duplicate or no duplicate.
@tompynation: which way does it behave?

Comment: After filter, it'll be reduced to zero or one.

Comment: Yeah so in zero case the subscribe wont be executed an the loading overlay or what ever wont be disabled, or I am wrong? oO

Comment: @J. Knabenschuh you are right... the final subscribe should allways get executed so the loading property get sets to false.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i implemented the suggestion as follows:

```
    this.loading = true;

    this.kandidatuurService.checkIfOndernemingsnummerAlreadyExists(this.onderneming.ondernemingsnummer)
      .pipe(
        tap((isDuplicate) => this.isDuplicate = isDuplicate),
        filter(x => x !== true),
        switchMap(() => this.requestService.selectOnderneming(this.onderneming))
      ).subscribe(v => { this.loading = false; this.ref.detectChanges(); });
```

but now the final subscribe is not being executed when it is a duplicate... Thats not really what i wanted...

Comment: OK, what's the expected behavior when it's a duplicate?

Comment: why do you save `isDuplicate` to this?

Comment: You can negate the `loading` flag here: `tap((isDuplicate) => { this.isDuplicate = isDuplicate); this.loading = this.loading && !isDuplicate; }`

Comment: I'm storing the isDuplicate because i need it afterwards inside the UI